# Are food availability questions on-topic on Travel-SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am kind of a food appreciator and amateur cook, so I always look forward to try samples of local cuisine everywhere I go. Sometimes, though, finding where a particular dish is served is not very easy, especially if it is localized to a certain region or not usually sought after by tourists.

So, my question is whether asking how to procure a certain dish are on-topic.

A sample question would probably go something like this:

> I'm in city X in Albania and I'm looking to try the famous tavë kosi - a dish with lamb, rice and yoghurt. I've checked a few restaurants around, but wasn't able to find it. Where can I try it? Is it localized to a certain region only, or does it have a different name I'm not aware of? Or is it made only during a specific time of the year?

General food recommendations of the type "I'm in city X, what can I eat here?" are of course soliciting opinions, and should be closed as usual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say finding food in city/country X is very travel applicable - similar to 'where can I find a Maori cultural experience in NZ', it's a part of the culture, and often as it's only accessible in particular countries, is an essential part of travel. I too try to look up the local foods before I enter a new country and try to locate them while I'm there - wikitravel.org has been a great resource thus far, and the fact it's on wiki*travel* shows how much a part of travel it is. Lonely Planet also features a food section, as does Rough Guide.

Elk soup in Tallinn, Estonia (as well as bear), reindeer in Finland, guinea pig in Peru, Malbec wine in Mendoza, Argentina - it's often a REASON people travel, not just a part of it. So I'd be definitely in favour of it being valid.

(aside, you should try Tave Kosi in Elbasan - where it's originally from, 1.5 hours SE of Tirana).

Comment: Dammit I think I'm further south than that here in Berat already. How did you find that info? The Wikipedia article is exceedingly skimpy. mindcorrosive suggested lamb might only be available in the spring which seems to make sense.

Comment: Err, on a couple of random recipe sites: http://www.setop.net/food-drink/tave-kosi-national-albanian-dish-lamb-and-yogurt-recipe.html mentions it, as does http://recipes.wikia.com/wiki/Tav%C3%AB_Kosi :)